# getServerSideProps not called on Link click if middleware is present - Next Js

Tags: next.js, next.js13

I am navigate to a different route through Link component. When the system does not have middleware.ts file, it is working fine. But when the system has middleware.ts file and the destination route has getServerSideProps function, the getServerSideProps function is not called and hence the resulting page has no data.

When i looked it up on Next issues in github, one particular [thread](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/38408) offered a solution. But apparently, that solution works in Next 12 and not 13, and my project has Next 13.

The solution offered is to set the below code in the middleware file.

```
response.headers.set("x-middleware-cache", "no-cache");
```

Looking forward to the assistance.